# Не могу установить pip модули для Python

Tags: python, pip

Hесколько дней назад возникла проблема, из-за которой я не могу установить ни одного модуля c `pip`. По логам увидел `Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение`, после каждый день пытался найти в инете решения, но не смог.

**Способы которые я уже испробовал:**

- запуск консоли от имени администратора;
- переустановка python;
- использование команды --trusted-host=;
- использовал --trusted-host= с разными прокси (--proxy=тут прокси);
- установил python на ноуте и вылезла та же ошибка, так что вполне вероятно дело в самом интернете или фаерволле.

ОС: [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10)

Python: [python-3.8](/questions/tagged/python-3.8)

[pip](/questions/tagged/pip) : 20.1.1

**Тут логи**:

```
pip install pygame

Collecting pygame
  
   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/a8/1e/5da797179ce046decc7d6d57a9b1977218103ccfb099b959b7736aff5f73/pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  
   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/a8/1e/5da797179ce046decc7d6d57a9b1977218103ccfb099b959b7736aff5f73/pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/a8/1e/5da797179ce046decc7d6d57a9b1977218103ccfb099b959b7736aff5f73/pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/a8/1e/5da797179ce046decc7d6d57a9b1977218103ccfb099b959b7736aff5f73/pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
  
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))': /packages/a8/1e/5da797179ce046decc7d6d57a9b1977218103ccfb099b959b7736aff5f73/pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/a8/1e/5da797179ce046decc7d6d57a9b1977218103ccfb099b959b7736aff5f73/pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)))
```

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог - - галочка  слева от ответа

Comment: Попробовал pip3 install --user и pip3 install pip --upgrade, но результат все тот же.

Comment: По идее вам должен помочь именно что trusted-host. Т.е. команда должна быть вида:

    pip install pygame --trusted-host pygame.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Проблема в том, что пакет может требовать сразу нескольких хостов, например у меня была аналогичная ошибка при установке cx_Oracle и помогло добавление двух хостов: pypi.org  и files.pythonhosted.org. Посмотрите все запрашиваемые хосты и добавьте их в команду установки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порыскав еще несколько дней и ничего не найдя, я решил проверить самый последний вариант. Провайдер. Позвонив своим друзьям, я попросил их установить питон и вбить ту команду для установки модуля. У всех без проблем установилось и у каждого был разный провайдер.
Изменив провайдера у меня моментально получилось установить модуль, как я и думал. Спасибо всем, кто помог с этим вопросом.

Логи:

pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
Downloading pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (4.8 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 4.8 MB 273 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.6

Answer (score 2):

1. ```
   pip3 install --user package-name  # for Python3
   pip install --user package-name  # for Python2
   ```
2. ```
   pip3 install pip --upgrade # for Python3
   pip install pip --upgrade # for Python2
   ```

---

[***source***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807507/could-not-install-packages-due-to-a-environment-error-error-13-permission-d)

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10
После установки `python 3.10` начал обновлять пакеты, получил аналогичную ошибку используя

```py
pip install namepackage
```

Решение:  Нужно использовать

```py
python -m pip install namepackage
```